# Contant Indents in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background, margin

I can not press the right and left edge of the content, please explain what I'm doing wrong? Where are the margins at number 1 and 2, with image?

[image]

And why the sidebar background not drop on 100% height of the page? (number 3 on image)

My code live - [here](http://dohms.ru/ecommerce/designers/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the container class from your html. The container centers the page and because of that your content is not snapping to left and right.

Comment: Change, it works, but problem number 3 (from image) doesnt solved, bg is not 100% height of page